# Why doesn't customSerialQueue.sync inside DispatchQueue.main.async deadlock, while DispatchQueue.main.sync does?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have two code blocks, one using `DispatchQueue.main.sync` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`, and another using a `customSerialQueue.sync` instead of `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. The first block causes a deadlock, while the second doesn't. I'm wondering why this is the case.

Here's the first block of code that deadlocks:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        print("this won't print")
    }
}
```

The `DispatchQueue.main.sync` call blocks the current thread it's executing on (which is the main thread), until the `print` statement executes on the main thread. However, the main thread is already blocked by the `DispatchQueue.main.sync` call, resulting in a deadlock.

And here's the second block of code that doesn't deadlock:

```swift
let customSerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.serialqueue")

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // main thread
    customSerialQueue.sync {
        print("this will print")  // main thread
    }
}
```

As for my understanding, calling `customSerialQueue.sync` **reuses** the thread (which happens to be the main thread) to run the block. I confirmed it really does by using breakpoints in Xcode. So I assumed this would also lead to deadlock, similar to the case in the first code block.

I wonder what's the difference between the two, and why the second one doesn't deadlock.

Comment: GCD is concerned with queues, not threads. In the first case you're blocking the *main queue*, not the *main thread*. In the second case you are not blocking the *main queue*. Your `print` statement executes in the main thread because it is available.

Comment: @Paulw11 The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271150/dispatchqueue-sync-blocks-thread-or-queue) suggests that `sync` blocks the current thread, not the queue. Can you please share any reference that suggests otherwise?

Comment: In that answer Rob explains that dispatching from a serial queue to itself will deadlock. This is what is happening in your first code block. I have to disagree a little with Rob's explanation as he doesn't emphasise the difference between serial and concurrent queues. Dispatching sync onto a concurrent dispatch queue blocks the thread, but as you have clearly shown, you have not blocked the main thread since it is available to execute your code in the second code block. GCD can block at the queue level for a serial dispatch queue because there is no need to worry about concurrency

Comment: @Paulw11 - Concurrent queues are not relevant here. Shinhong’s question deals solely with serial queues. Also, I disagree with your claim that shinhong has “not blocked the main thread”.  `sync` blocks the caller’s thread. All you are seeing is a clever little optimization whereby `sync` avails itself of the thread that it has otherwise blocked. It’s the whole purpose of that optimization, to avoid costly thread switch.

Comment: So the thread is not blocked. The main queue is blocked. If the thread was blocked (at the thread level) then sync could not perform its neat trick.

Comment: I hear you, but respectfully disagree. Nothing (other than what `sync` is doing in its optimization) can run on the main thread. Sure, the main thread is doing *something* (namely, what was in the `sync` closure) but “blocked” doesn't mean that the thread is necessarily idle (e.g., a `sleep` or what have you), but merely that it can't do anything else until it is unblocked. It would be akin to saying that spinning indefinitely on a thread (e.g., `while true { }`) doesn't “block” that thread. It does. It's busy, for sure, but is blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted (and as I have noted in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277760/1271826)), dispatching synchronously from a serial queue to itself will always deadlock. And this makes perfect sense. Because it is synchronous, you are blocking the caller’s thread (and because the caller was on a serial queue, blocking that entire serial queue) waiting for additional code dispatched to that very same blocked serial queue to run.

The `sync` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync) sums it up concisely:

> Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock.

That is, admittedly, an over simplification (because it only guarantees a deadlock if the current queue is a serial queue or you exhaust the worker thread pool), but it confirms your experience.

Before we get to the question as to why the second example does not deadlock, let’s explain (for readers unfamiliar with the underlying optimization) what is going on. When you dispatch synchronously with `sync`, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync) tells us:

> As a performance optimization, this function executes blocks on the current thread whenever possible …

Effectively, what is going on, is that libDispatch is smart enough to say, “hey, if the current thread is blocked anyway, whenever possible, why don’t we just avoid the costly context switch from one thread to another and instead just run the dispatched code on the current thread.” There are admittedly exceptions to this clever little optimization, but they aren’t relevant here, so I won’t belabor them.

So, I might rephrase your characterization that `sync` “reuses the thread.” I think it is more accurate to say that it just never leaves that thread at all if it knows it’s going to be blocked/idle in the interim, anyway. That’s the whole point of the optimization, namely to avoid a costly context switch.

In short, the answer to your original question is that in your first example, you are dispatching synchronously to a blocked queue, whereas in the second example, you are dispatching synchronously to a different, unblocked queue. It is mildly interesting that the `sync` optimization lets this latter example continue execution on the current *thread,* but that is not relevent here. The *queue* to which you are dispatching in the second example is not blocked.